# Flow: Why does `instanceof Type` fail?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I seriously cannot think of a more basic use case of Union types than this:

**test.js**

```
// @flow
type Foo = {
  a: string,
  b: number
}

function func(o: Foo | string) {
  if (o instanceof Foo) {            // <<<<< ERROR
    console.log(o.a);
  } else {
    console.log(o);
  }
}
```

Flow gives me an error on the line:

```
o instanceof Foo
```

with this:

```
Cannot reference type Foo [1] from a value position.
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I make this logic work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, `Foo` is just a Flow type (which gets stripped from compiled code), but [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) is native JavaScript.

JavaScript's `instanceof` works by checking if an object is an instance of a constructor function. It has no knowledge of your Flow types, and cannot check if an object is that type.

You might want to use `typeof` instead.

```
function func(o: Foo | string) {
  if (typeof o === 'string') {
    console.log(o);
  } else {
    console.log(o.a);
  }
}
```